# Deployment of Microsoft stack apps without reinventing the wheel

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2008, vs-web-application-project, web-farm

We have the following three things we need to deploy to a Windows Server 2008 farm:

- ASP.NET MVC 4 web applications (x3)
- .NET Windows services (x2)

I have inherited the deploy process and would like to rewrite it.

### Web Applications

When I am in Visual Studio 2012 I have a nice new publishing wizard for deploying web applications. Can this be used somehow? Or taken advantage of in anyway?

### Windows Services

Windows Services are Windows Services, so deploying them to a Windows Server should be simple. Right?!

Then there is how to deal with the fact we are deploying to a *farm* of Windows Server 2008 machines, not just one.

Everyone I talk to seems to have to reinvent a new, custom and complex process that is difficult to maintain and not very malleable, often with custom XML files with all sorts of actions etc that are hand edited. Even psexec gets involved a lot - this smells wrong to me.

Given that at least for the service and the web applications we *are doing nothing special whatsoever*, what is the simplest way to have a nice, potentially VCS commitable publishing process.

Apologies if this is a ridiculous question, if so please help me understand why!

To be a question on here though, it needs to be answerable. So to summise: what is the easiest/an easy way to deploy web applications and windows services to a farm of Windows Server 2008 machines?

Comment: Is this question maybe more appropriate for http://superuser.com?

Comment: I really wasn't sure, to be honest. It felt wrong there because it's really aimed at developers.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do this would be to build your deployment on WinRS (remote power-shell) which uses WinRM for its communication and authentication. WinRM is a bit of a learning curve to configure if you want to step off the golden path though, as I've been finding recently :).

Almost all the configuration services you need (firewall=>netsh, Remote management=winrm, services=>sc, Windows features=>dism, Event Collection=>winecutil, gpupdate, etc) are available as command-line tools and often also directly supported in PowerShell, so you don't need to code anything to the APIs.